# how this statement getting compared in VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

In below code if statement is between integers, that I am not getting how its comparing ? 
I want it to replicate in C#.net

```
Public Function QSBarcodeCheckLicenseVersion(ByRef eVersionToCheck As enmBC_LIC_Version) As Boolean
    Dim lLicense As Integer

    lLicense = 8

    **If lLicense And eVersionToCheck Then**
        QSBarcodeCheckLicenseVersion = True
    Else
        QSBarcodeCheckLicenseVersion = False
    End If

End Function

Public Enum enmBC_LIC_Version
    BC_LIC_DEMO = &H1
    BC_LIC_LINEAR = &H2
    BC_LIC_PDF417 = &H4
    BC_LIC_DATAM = &H8
End Enum
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a bitwise `and`:

```
if ((ILicence & (int)eVersionToCheck) != 0)
```

The actual implementation would then be:

```
public bool QSBarcodeCheckLicenseVersion(enmBC_LIC_Version eVersionToCheck)
{ 
   Int32 lLicense = 8;

   return ((lLicense & (int)eVersionToCheck) != 0);            
}
```

**NOTE**

However, you could re-write the method to use only enum values as @SwDevMan81 showed in his answer. That's probably better form as far as using enums!

[Demo Here](http://rextester.com/live/KILUM26639)

Comment: @NeerajKumarGupta - plase see updated code. It turns out you do have to explicitly cast the enum to an Int32..

Answer (score 1):

Its doing a Bitwise compare.  In C# you can use '&'.

```
// Pseudo code
QSBarcodeCheckLicenseVersion = (lLicense & eVersionToCheck);
```

Actual version:

```
void Main()
{
    enmBC_LIC_Version v = enmBC_LIC_Version.BC_LIC_LINEAR /*| enmBC_LIC_Version.BC_LIC_DATAM*/;
    bool outp = QSBarcodeCheckLicenseVersionFunc(v);
    Console.WriteLine(outp);
}

public bool QSBarcodeCheckLicenseVersionFunc(enmBC_LIC_Version eVersionToCheck)
{
    enmBC_LIC_Version lLicense = enmBC_LIC_Version.BC_LIC_DATAM;
    return ((lLicense & eVersionToCheck) == lLicense);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
[Flags]
public enum enmBC_LIC_Version
{
    BC_LIC_DEMO = 0x01,
    BC_LIC_LINEAR = 0x02,
    BC_LIC_PDF417 = 0x04,
    BC_LIC_DATAM = 0x08
}
```

In .NET 4.0 and later, you can use [HasFlag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx)

```
return eVersionToCheck.HasFlag(lLicense);
```

Comment: That syntax for returning a value isn't valid in C#.

Comment: @Servy - Update with complete example and marked example code as Pseudo.

Answer (score -1):

`enmBC_LIC_Version`, being an enumeration, is just an integer behind the scenes with fancy names for different literal values.  The code is performing a bitwise AND on that number with the number `8`.  Since 8 is one of the valid enums, the result will be 0 if the enum isn't `BC_LIC_DATAM`.  So in short, it's seeing if the enum is set to `BC_LIC_DATAM`.

In C# you will use `&` to do a bitwise AND, so the function will look like:

```
return (enmBC_LIC_Version.BC_LIC_DATAM & eVersionToCheck) != 0;
```

(Note I used `enmBC_LIC_Version.BC_LIC_DATAM` rather than `8` as it makes it *much* easier to read the code.)

Answer (score -1):

```
Public bool QSBarcodeCheckLicenseVersion(enmBC_LIC_Version eVersionToCheck)
{
    int lLicense = 8;

    if ((lLicense & eVersionToCheck) != 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

Public enum enmBC_LIC_Version
{
    BC_LIC_DEMO = 1,
    BC_LIC_LINEAR = 2,
    BC_LIC_PDF417 = 4,
    BC_LIC_DATAM = 8
}
```

apparently Servy is right.  I could have sworn int evaluated directly to bool on the basis of 0==false.  Dunno which language that's valid in.

Comment: `lLicense && eVersionToCheck` won't compile.  He needs a bitwise AND

Comment: it will compile with the &&; however, you're probably right about the intention of the questioner

Comment: No, it won't compile.  The && operator must accept arguments of type bool and bool, not `enmBC_LIC_Version` and `int`, and that's exactly what the syntax error it produces will tell you.

Comment: It doesn't even *get* to an `if` statement, `lLicense && eVersionToCheck` doesn't compile as an expression on it's own, because `operator &&` only accepts arguments of `bool` and `bool`.  I'm looking at the compiler error right now.  Perhaps you should try compiling it yourself.  Yes you can compare an `int` and an enum in an `if` block, but only if you use the proper operator/method to do so.